# Angular "navigate" to 404 but keep url

Tags: angular, redirect, router

I have checked many questions and the internet without any luck, so maybe someone had a similar issue...

I implemented a lazy loaded module:

```
  {
    component: LoginPageComponent,
    path: '',
    pathMatch: 'full'
  },
  {
    canActivate: [AuthGuard],
    loadChildren: () => import('./modules/home/home.module').then(m => m.HomeModule),
    path: 'home'
  },
```

And in HomeRoutingModule I have an another

```
....
 children: [
      ...
      {
        path: 'items',
        canActivate: [SomeGuard,
        loadChildren: () => ....
      },
```

Then finally in that child lazy loaded module routing:

```
{
    path: 'preview/:id',
    canActivate: [ItemLoadedGuard],
    component: PreviewPageComponent
  },
```

so URL for some entry will be eg: `/home/items/preview/some-random-id`. In that `ItemLoaderGuard` I implement BE call for that resource and on error it navigates to 404 page.

But with that implementation when I pass:
`/home/items/preview/wrong-id`
I'll be redirected to `/404` page.

What I wanna to do is keep url and open up 404 page component so:
`/home/items/preview/wrong-id` use NotFoundPageComponent instead of PreviewPageComponent

I've tried with navigation extras like: `skipLocationChange` and `replaceUrl` but with no effect.

Is there any other way to handle this instead of adding some wrapper in PreviewPageComponent that will display not found or not (sample code below)?

```
<not-found *ngIf="displayNotFound"></not-found>
<div class="content" *ngIf="!displayNotFound">
....
</div>
```

I was also thinking about storing url in Local Storage, navigate to 404 then replace url without path, but maybe someone has better solution?

DEMO: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-404

Comment: please provide a stackblitz.

Comment: @AakashGarg added

Comment: find answer below, and please vote if it helps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change your preview.guard.ts to

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { CanActivate, ActivatedRouteSnapshot, RouterStateSnapshot, Router } from '@angular/router';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({providedIn: 'root'})
export class PreviewGuard implements CanActivate {

constructor(private router: Router){}

  canActivate(
    next: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
    state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean> | Promise<boolean> | boolean {
    if(next.params.id === '123-works'){
      console.log('allowed')
      return true;
    } else {
      console.log('not allowed');
      setTimeout(() => this.router.navigateByUrl('404', {skipLocationChange: true}));
      return true;
    }
  }
}
```

**How it works**

Actually when you refereshed, you previous url was of home page not 'wrong-id', when guard sent false the previous url became of home page and return false takes you to previous url. what i did here is allowed that url to get activated and because i kept routing to 404 in settimeout, it will kick in after navigation to 'wrong-id'

Comment: Weird but works. Thanks. I'm thinking about how it works behind the scenes?